# Undefined behaviour in Intel safestringlib

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In Intel's [safestringlib](https://github.com/intel/safestringlib) there is an open bug on undefined behaviour in
`memcpy_s` API, when it compares pointers from (potential) different allocated objects:

```
if( ((dp > sp) && (dp < (sp+smax))) ||
((sp > dp) && (sp < (dp+dmax))) )
```

Where `dp` and `sp` are of `uint8_t` pointer types that violates *C11 § 6.5.8 paragraph 5* [Issue (#18): https://github.com/intel/safestringlib/issues/18 (status: open)]

Now, I suspect there is another UB in `strncpy_s` [API](https://github.com/intel/safestringlib/blob/245c4b8cff1d2e7338b7f3a82828fc8e72b29549/safeclib/strncpy_s.c#L151):

```
   if (dest < src) {                        //HERE
       overlap_bumper = src;
```

`dest` and `src` are `char` pointers, so the `if (dest < src)` compares pointers from different allocated objects, as in the `memcpy_s` bug (UB #1).

Am I right with my suspicion?

Comment: "Two pointers compare equal if and only if ..." so *UB#2* is not a UB... those pointer just will not be equal...

Comment: @AlexLop. Yes you're right, question edited. Is UB#1 in `strncpy_s` is indeed another UB?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `strncpy_s` API source that you are talking about?

Comment: @AlexLop. provided, question edited.

Comment: Looks like all the '\*cpy\*' functions have this *UB*

Comment: *Am I right with my suspicion?* I'd say yes. I'd note, though, that Intel's library appears to have started as an **implementation** of a standard C function for a specific architecture known to behave in a specific way.  As an actual implementation, it's not bound by the C standard itself and when undefined behavior would otherwise happen it's free to define its behavior any way it likes and can take advantage of platform-specific behavior to do so.  Making such code "generic" C code and not an actual implementation of a C runtime environment does remove that freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as @AlexLop mentioned, there are multiple occurrences of that kind of undefined behavior in the library.

A quick test with Frama-C shows some occurrences of `\pointer_comparable` alarms. Among other things, these alarms indicate usage of comparison operators between different objects, which is UB.

For instance, running the following command:

```
frama-c-gui safeclib/*.c unittests/test_strncpy_s.c -main test_strncpy_s \
  -cpp-extra-args="-Iinclude" -eva -eva-precision 3
```

Does show in the GUI that there are several callstacks in which pointers from `str1` and `str2` are compared (though in at least one callstack the pointers point to the same global variable, so in that case it is valid).

[image: Screenshot of the Frama-C GUI showing the alarm and values computed by Eva, per callstack]